# Calendar custom event types

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

Was looking at the [Calendar Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) documentation because I need to add events to the google calendar.

My app will be able to list the events on the calendar or create new events.

Is it possible to create a custom event, that is, it signals that it was created by my app so that, after inserting the event on the google calendar, on my app, I can only list the events that were created by my app? Is there any flag that signals the event creation app/owner, etc?

Comment: I think there is no way through the calendar provider (as extended properties are often not synced and there is no special field). You could take a look at using the calendar API Android client library or work around by appending a string at the end of the description field or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ExtendedProperties`. Here is [docmunetation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.ExtendedProperties.html). This table is used by sync adapters to add extra information. However you can insert a name/value pair in this table such as a `boolean` when inserting events. You will use this field when you query events to find out event are from your app or not.

Comment: Thanks. Any tougth on this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611533/android-calendar-provider-disable-sending-email-to-attendees)?